# Python Convert str with list to list

Tags: python

I have message which is a list and JSON in it. I managed to get JSON with raw decode. The problem is

```
string = "["a,b","b,c"]"
```

How can I convert that string into a list?

Comment: This is not a valid python string.

Comment: `json.decode` it again? For the record, that's not the string you have (the lack of escaped quotes/failure to use different quotes for inner/outer quotes means it's syntactically invalid as a string literal).

Answer (score 0):

Use `ast.literal_eval`:

```py
import ast

print(ast.literal_eval(string))
```

Since this is JSON, use the `json` module:

```py
import json

print(json.loads(string))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "['a,b','b,c']"

print(eval(string))
```

Comment: No! Don't use eval! This is unsafe!

Comment: Why/how does this work, and why is it dangerous in the context of the question?